# I need someone to ELI5 this Skrollr.js feature

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, skrollr

Pausing. I essentially need to use skrollr.js to pause on a div i have, that contains an image. I know this probably isn't that difficult but I just can't seem to get it right. So could someone please just explain briefly how to make this happen?

```
<div> Something </div>
<div> <img> </div> <-----div to pause on for a little while
<div> Something else </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

taken from [this](https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-scrolling-slideshow-using-skrollr/) tutorial.

Pausing a scrolling animation

Lets say we want to freeze each of the slides for 50% of the viewport height.

In other words we don’t want the Slide 2 and 3 move for a while and then scroll to the next slide.

We can include empty data attributes to create a keyframe and change the animation offsets.

The updated data-attributes would like this:

```
<div id="slides"
data-0="transform:translate(0%,0%);"
data-50p=""
data-150p="transform:translate(0%,-50%);"
data-200p=""
data-300p="transform:translate(-50%,-50%);"
data-350p=""
data-450p="transform:translate(-50%,0%);"
>
```

Now every slide stays fixed for a while before scrolling to the next one.